# Text out of its div (overflow)

Tags: css

http://maniamicizia.it/index.php?page=home&lang=it

I have based my website on `float:left` and that is working nice (IE isn't just because of the rgba background and adapted background). I'm now having this strange issue that prevent the text from standing in its own div.

Here is the CSS/HTML

```
<div style='
border:10px solid rgb(239,226,173);
background:rgba(200,200,200,0.7);
margin-left:320px;
margin-top:290px;
width:150px;
height:200px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 1);
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
'> Hello World </div>
```

Just...why? I know how to handle the position, but why is the text going out like that?
The div is "*obviously*" the one on the right of the post-it.

Comment: All your layout is not very good, read about clearfix class and use some layout bootstrap like Twitter Bootstrap

Comment: What version of IE is the problem?  I looked at it in IE9 and the text is completely inside the div...

Answer (score 1):

I tried it myself, but the text is not overflowing at all, it stays inside the div. Probably you are inheriting an style attribute from a parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left;` in your element style to keep the text inside its desired box.

```
<div style="
border:10px solid rgb(239,226,173);
background:rgba(200,200,200,0.7);
margin-left:320px;
margin-top:220px;
width:150px;
height:200px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 1);
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
float:left;">

Wth am I doing here?

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have the text in the box, but it was the box to move and not the text, as I wanted to. How to solve this (I try to avoid negative margins)?